# Cast exception when querying on index

Tags: ravendb

I have an index that looks like this

```
public class FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel : Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask<FeedPost, FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public long SequentialId { get; set; }
        public string AnnouncementId { get; set; }
        public string Label1 { get; set; }
        public string FeedOwner { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
    public FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel()
    {
        Map = announcements => from doc in announcements
                               from docLabelsItem1 in ((IEnumerable<Label>)doc.Labels).DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new Result
                               {
                                   SequentialId = doc.SequentialId,
                                   AnnouncementId = doc.AnnouncementId,
                                   CreationDate = doc.CreationDate,
                                   FeedOwner = doc.FeedOwner,
                                   Label1 = docLabelsItem1.Text
                               };
    }
}
```

And I query it like this (simplified version, which STILL fails):

```
from c in _session.Query<FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel.Result, FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel>()
                                   select c;
```

I get an exception EVERY TIME I query it. The really odd thing is that this used to work. Im not sure if its broken since I updated Raven to the latest version - or because of something else I changed.
Im pretty sure the only thing thats changes is that I moved "FeedPost" into its own DLL (with various DataContract attributes on it).

Any takers??

Thanks

```
<Exception xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException</ExceptionType>
<Message>
Unable to cast object of type 'FeedPost' to type 'Result'.
</Message>
<StackTrace>
at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.ConvertToEntity[T](String id, RavenJObject documentFound, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 416
 at Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T](String key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.cs:line 340
 at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T](RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 130
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete[T]() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:line 114
 at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 603
 at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:line 98
 at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at FeedPostsController.Get(String labels, Int32 sincePostId) in FeedPostsController.cs:line 211
 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.Execute(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeActionAsync>b__0()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
</StackTrace>
</Exception>
```

[UPDATE]

Ok - I moved the FeedPost definition back into the same DLL that had the indices... still fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this (https://gist.github.com/2780374) and I m not getting that error (ie the query runs without errors) tho no results

It seems like you are trying to get all the feed annoucement by labels then maybe this could work?
I removed the annoucementId and the other id because it would get in the way of the aggregation (by label) but maybe I got your domain wrong.

```
    public class FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel : AbstractIndexCreationTask<FeedPost, FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Label1 { get; set; }
        public string FeedOwner { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
    public FeedAnnouncementByOneLabel()
    {
        Map = announcements => from doc in announcements
                               from label in doc.Labels.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new 
                               {
                                   CreationDate = (DateTimeOffset)doc.CreationDate,
                                   FeedOwner = doc.FeedOwner,
                                   Label1 = label.Text
                               };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Label1
                                into r
                                select new
                                {
                                    CreationDate = (DateTimeOffset)r.Max(x => x.CreationDate),
                                    FeedOwner = r.Select(x=> x.FeedOwner).First(),
                                    Label1 = r.Key,
                                };
    }
}
```